# Get IE's default proxy with DefaultWebProxy

Tags: c#, proxy, system.net, system.net.httpwebrequest

I've read through pretty much all the documentation I can find but I'm yet to find a simple working example of how to get IE's default proxy settings using `DefaultWebProxy()`.

This code seems to compile and work but how do I then go ahead and get the proxy URI as a string?

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = 
    (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");

if (WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy != null)
{
    webRequest.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Since submitting this question I have found that one or many proxies can be set for different destinations or bypassed (perhaps for local intranet destinations).  That's why you need to specify a URI to `GetProxy()`.  It needs to know which destination to get the proxy for.  If "Automatically Detect Settings" is set in Internet Options the browser will look for a PAC file on your local domain.  The PAC file contains a Javascript function which determines the proxy address for a given destination.

Comment: It's not Java, it's Javascript that is used in the PAC file.

Comment: @Maxence Thanks I'll make an edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` implements the [`IWebProxy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iwebproxy.aspx) interface. You can use the [`GetProxy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iwebproxy.getproxy.aspx) method to get the proxy's URI:

```
var uri = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.GetProxy(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
```

Response to a comment:

You need to pass the uri to `GetProxy` because that's how Microsoft implemented it...

Seriously, I believe this is so because you can configure the browser to bypass the proxy for some addresses. If you pass one of this bypassed addresses, you will probably get a different result.

Comment: Can you also explain why we need to specify a URL of a site?

Comment: Also, I think GetProxy requires an instance of URI as input rather than a string

Comment: I'm using the above solution but have one problem with it: When I set the proxy config to be a local file: file://c:/temp/myconfig.pac IE loads and uses it but my .Net app ignores it and always runs without proxy... Any ideas?

Comment: I think you might need to post it as another question.  It might help to see the code.