# How to get Proxy Address using WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy while the IE is Mapped to .PAC

Tags: c#, winforms, proxy, webproxy

I am using a .Pac file in IE by setting Use automatic configuration script to true. Everything works fine ie pinging and all, but when i try to resolve the Proxy address by using webproxy it always gives me null. From the last two day i am on to it any help will be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe this SO thread can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078894/get-ies-default-proxy-with-defaultwebproxy