# How to set a proxy auto-configuration script (.pac) to be used in C#?

Tags: c#, proxy, pac

I'm starting to write some very simple web-apps in C# and occasionally I get exceptions about not having a proxy configured. I am in a work environment that has a rather strict proxy auto-configuration file (.pac -- Proxy Auto-Config).

Is there a way to tell C# to use that .pac file for proxy settings?

Comment: I don't know you to use a specific .pac file, but had similar proxy problems a while ago. The solution I found was to tell my app to use the Windows default proxy settings (and credentials). That is, what your browser probably does. If that is sufficient, I'll post some code.

Comment: This might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078894/get-ies-default-proxy-with-defaultwebproxy

Comment: I've had success by adding the '<system.net> <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" /> </system.net>' code to the App.config file **in addition to** checking the "Automatically Detect Settings" box in IE under Tools->Internet Options->Connections->Lan Settings. Oddly enough, some days just checking the box in IE will solve the issue. Other days I need to add the system.net code to my App.config. That issue I still haven't figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET can use the default proxy settings of the user running the code. It uses the same settings that are defined for IE. See this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkwyc043%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

You should also see this SO post about MIME types for the PAC file: [Using Proxy Automatic Configuration from IE Settings in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552227/using-proxy-automatic-configuration-from-ie-settings-in-net)